# smiley face key in Qt Virtual Keyboard

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am using Qt VirtualKeyboard on a raspberry pi and it is working fine for most part but when the keyboard appears, it is shown as:

[image]

Now there is this smiley face key on the bottom right and I am not sure what I need to do to get rid of it. I copied a style file which I can load but it does not seem to appear anywhere in the style description. I also looked in the textfield qml hints here (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#inputMethodHints-prop) and it does not seem to have anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the [`Key` from the last `KeyboardRow` in symbols.qml](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git/tree/src/virtualkeyboard/content/layouts/en_GB/symbols.qml#n196):

```
Key {
    key: 0xE000
    text: ":-)"
    alternativeKeys: [ ";-)", ":-)", ":-D", ":-(", "<3" ]
}
```

Then the code will look like this:

```
KeyboardRow {
    keyWeight: 154
    SymbolModeKey {
        weight: 217
        displayText: "ABC"
    }
    ChangeLanguageKey {
        weight: 154
    }
    SpaceKey {
        weight: 864
    }
    Key {
        key: Qt.Key_Period
        text: "."
        alternativeKeys: ".,"
    }
    HideKeyboardKey {
        weight: 204
    }
}
```

You may also need to ajust the [`weight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-basekey.html#weight-prop) properties if the keys look too big or small afterwards.

Comment: Ah yes ok. I will see if I can copy the layout and create a new one rather than edit the default one. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Would this have to be done for every single layout? Ie if I want to use all the languages would I have to individual alter all of their symbols.qml files?